# save as event in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have developed an addin for excel using VSTO(C#).

I wish to know whenever the workbook is '**SAVED AS**' during runtime. ie. the user is performing some operation on WBK 1 and then he saves the work book using SAVE AS and then renames the workbook and again starts working on it. SO in this case is it possible to catch the 'Worlbook SAve AS' event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Application.WorkbookAfterSave event passes in a WorkBook object named `wb` and a boolean named `Success`.

You can get the saved as filename from the FullName property of the Workbook object. Maybe you could store the initial name in a variable, and on the AfterSave event compare the names and locations to see if Save As has been used like so:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private string CurrentFullName { get; set; }
        private event EventHandler SaveAs;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentFullName = this.Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName;

            this.Application.WorkbookAfterSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookAfterSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookAfterSave);

            SaveAs += new EventHandler(ThisAddIn_SaveAs);
        }

        void ThisAddIn_SaveAs(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do What I want to do if saved as
        }

        void Application_WorkbookAfterSave(Excel.Workbook Wb, bool Success)
        {
            if (Wb.FullName != CurrentFullName)
            {
                CurrentFullName = Wb.FullName;
                SaveAs.Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```